# pyspark/dataframe: replace null with empty space

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

I have the following udf function in pyspark dataframe. The code works fine except when `myFun1('oldColumn')` is null, I want the output to be empty string instead of null.

```
myFun1 = udf(lambda x: myModule.myFunction1(x), StringType())
myDF = myDF.withColumn('newColumn', myFun1('oldColumn'))
```

Is it possible to do this in place instead of create another udf function? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Using `df.fillna()` or `df.na.fill()` to replace null values with an empty string worked for me.

You can do replacements by column by supplying the column and value you want to replace nulls with as a parameter:

```
myDF = myDF.na.fill({'oldColumn': ''})
```

The Pyspark docs have [an example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna) :

```
>>> df4.na.fill({'age': 50, 'name': 'unknown'}).show()
+---+------+-------+
|age|height|   name|
+---+------+-------+
| 10|    80|  Alice|
|  5|  null|    Bob|
| 50|  null|    Tom|
| 50|  null|unknown|
+---+------+-------+
```